# echo %tmp% prints directory that doesn't exist

Tags: environment-variables, temporary-files, windows-server-2019

I encountered an issue with a customer where Path.GetTempFileName() in a .NET Framework application was returning an invalid directory. In troubleshooting, I found that:

```
> echo %tmp%
```

was returning a path like this:

```
C:\Users\twils\AppData\Local\Temp\2
```

but there was no 2 subfolder in the Temp directory. We checked the environment variables for the user and the TMP variable pointed to:

```
C:\Users\twils\AppData\Local\Temp
```

Where is this extra "\2" coming from? We created that folder and the issue was resolved, but I'm not satisfied. The operating system was Windows Server 2019 and this was in a corporate environment.

Comment: There can be variables pointing to folders that don't exist, or don't exist anymore. When you have a variable that points to folder and you delete that folder the variable remains despite the folder having been deleted long time ago or even never existed.

Comment: Have you checked the TMP variable for both System and User?